# CouchApp views show up will null results

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchapp

I am new to CouchDB, but I am coming up empty trying to Google for this.

I have a view which has a result set of 2 documents when viewed from the DB
host:5984/_utils/database.html?phistory/_design/phistory/_view/res

When I try to access this same view via a couch app, the results come back as a null document.
host:5984/phistory/_design/phistory/_view/res

Result JSON when viewed from CouchApp:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":null}
]}
```

Here is the map function from the view.

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.query && doc.transactions){
    emit(doc.query, doc.transactions);
  }  
}
```

Document

```
{
   "_id": "fad95bf61bd2c87db4d017668a002191",
   "_rev": "1-8bec74cf8022f91bdc9cb53fa8ff7599",
   "query_group": "simple-select",
   "query": "select id from FactV__c",
   "transactions": {
       "2011-06-01T12:13:15Z": "100",
       "2011-07-01T12:13:15Z": "099"
   }
}
```

According to this it looks like I am accessing the view correctly.
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Adding debug output from the couch log for the request.  You can see below that the actual view rendered the data from the DB perspective, but returned null to the response to the browser.

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.957.0>] 'GET' /phistory/_design/phistory/_view/res {1,1}
Headers: [{'Accept',"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"},
          {'Accept-Charset',"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"},
          {'Accept-Encoding',"gzip,deflate,sdch"},
          {'Accept-Language',"en-US,en;q=0.8"},
          {'Connection',"keep-alive"},
          {'Cookie',"AuthSession=YnVpbGQ6NEUxREUzNTk6suAhrCjMRNN100LLDJqb0Dl-0Ag"},
          {'Host',"cmarcel-ws:5984"},
          {'If-None-Match',"\"5WLSLFYCQ880T9JCCPAMD804R\""},
          {'User-Agent',"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"},
          {"X-Purpose",": preview"}]

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.957.0>] Successful cookie auth as: "build"

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.957.0>] request_group {Pid, Seq} {<0.907.0>,96}

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.957.0>] request_group {Pid, Seq} {<0.907.0>,96}

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.918.0>] OS Process #Port<0.2202> Input  :: ["reset",{"reduce_limit":true}]

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.918.0>] OS Process #Port<0.2202> Output :: true

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.918.0>] OS Process #Port<0.2202> Input  :: ["reduce",["function(keys, values, rereduce) {\n  \n}"],[[["select id from FactV__c","fad95bf61bd2c87db4d017668a002191"],{"2011-06-01T12:13:15Z":"100","2011-07-01T12:13:15Z":"099"}]]]

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [debug] [<0.918.0>] OS Process #Port<0.2202> Output :: [true,[null]]

[Wed, 13 Jul 2011 18:36:09 GMT] [info] [<0.957.0>] 10.0.63.48 - - 'GET' /phistory/_design/phistory/_view/res 200

Comment: Can you include some sample documents and your view's source code?

Comment: Here is the map function from the view.
`function(doc) {
  if(doc.query && doc.transactions){
    emit(doc.query, doc.transactions);
  }  
}

Document
{
   "_id": "fad95bf61bd2c87db4d017668a002191",
   "_rev": "1-8bec74cf8022f91bdc9cb53fa8ff7599",
   "query_group": "simple-select",
   "query": "select id from FactV__c",
   "transactions": {
       "2011-06-01T12:13:15Z": "100",
       "2011-07-01T12:13:15Z": "099"
   }
}`

Comment: Edit the question to include those details

Comment: UPdated with correct formatting in the question.

Comment: It works fine for me? Is there a reduce happening? What's the full URL you are using to query the view?

Comment: I'm fairly certain your reduce function is what the problem is, please include it here as well.

Comment: There is no reduce happening.  It is just the map. The full URL for the CouchApp is: http://remotehost:5984/phistory/_design/phistory/_view/res

Comment: Well, I put in an empty reduce function and that got me the `null` responses. Other than that, I'm not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: The view works and documents are returned when I look at it directly in the DB.  It is only when I try to access the view via the couch app that the results come back null.

Comment: Odd, then you need to include more code from your couchapp front-end then.

Comment: I am just trying to access the view via the URL from the app perspective. 

There is a phistory/views/res/map.js on disk that  that contains the map function above.  This gets pushed up to couch from couchapp.  When I push the app it creates the view in _view for the DB.  I wonder if its a permission thing.

Comment: Find the source for the design document that couchapp created.

Comment: Are you editing the view in the Futon?  I find that I play with views in Futon and then forget to click save and so when I go to the URL they are not working the same.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what was going on. Apparently when you generate views through couchapp it creates and empty reduce function as well.  It futon, you need to explicitly run the reduce so it didn't effect the results set.  Through the app the empty reduce effectively nulled out the results.  Thanks to all who responded.